# Flutter local notifications plugin show function is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Getting this error while showing notification

```
E/libc    ( 4794): Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/libc    ( 4794): Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.knock.type"
W/m.scaler.dhobe( 4794): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/m.scaler.dhobe( 4794): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/m.scaler.dhobe( 4794): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.scaler.dhobe( 4794): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/firebase-iid-ex( 4794): type=1400 audit(0.0:1176558): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1307 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_29:s0:c95,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.scaler.dhobee
W/m.scaler.dhobe( 4794): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.scaler.dhobe( 4794): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

This is code my code which I am using from sending notification

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"));
    notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "dhobeecustomer",
          "dhobeecustomer channel",
          "this is our channel",
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
      );
      print(
          "-----------------------------------------------------before displaying notification-----------------------------------------");
      print("inside LocalNotificationSerice");
      notificationsPlugin
          .show(id, message.notification.title, message.notification.body,
              notificationDetails)
          .onError((error, stackTrace) => print('Error--------->$error'));

      print(
          "-----------------------------------------------------after displaying notification-----------------------------------------");
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print("err--->$e");
    }
  }
}
```